# Symfony. Where should I place complex queries?

Tags: php, symfony, oop

I have a question. I'm working on symfony based web application. I faced with one issue. Where should I place complex queries with many joins? Should I create method in the repository class? Or it should be placed in the service layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repository class is a good way to go. I do not know what you mean by "service layer". You can define repository as a service, so it can be injected in controllers, commands or anything else. That will make your queries reusable in the whole project.

Comment: thank you for your answer. service layer I meant http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html

Answer (score 0):

It is highly architecture-specific.
Symfony is a framework, it does not require to be used with specific architecture pattern like Service layer, MVC, etc.

If you use Service layer with combination of Repository pattern,
the business logic should be in your service, and complex queries could be in your repositories

[image]